# Why is my chosen select dropdown not working in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am using chosen dropdown with search option; it's working fine with desktop but it is not working in mobile devices.

```
<select name="user_coming" id="user_coming" class="chosen-select">
    <option value="">How did you get here</option>
    <option value="Classified AD">Classified AD</option>
    <option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
    <option value="Friend/Family Members">Friend/Family Members</option>
    <option value="Health Club Poster">Health Club Poster</option>
    <option value="Internet Advertising">Internet Advertising</option>
    <option value="Marketing Team">Marketing Team</option>
    <option value="Newspaper/Magazine">Newspaper/Magazine</option>
    <option value="Radio Advertisement">Radio Advertisement</option>
    <option value="Tradeshows">Road shows</option>
    <option value="Search Engine Google">Search Engine Google</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i suggest use bootstrap select2 :- https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/

Comment: Can you describe what is the issue on mobile?

Comment: Check if you have placed your jQuery script properly. Check for any errors in your browser console.

Comment: NORA @ dropdown with search  is not working in mobile.

Comment: could you add some screen? There are some script that modify the select tag?

Comment: Eomm @ https://www.lifemadeeasyglobal.com/hyderabad/     please can you check on registration button here you can find dropdown.

Comment: As stated in the [faq questions](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#faqs): Chosen is disabled on iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android mobile devices.

Comment: Nora @ There is any alternate solution for this problem ?. please suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

Here the link and solution for your issue. http://realize.be/mobile-support-chosen