# Gravity form chosen for select not working on mobile device

Tags: wordpress, jquery-chosen, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have used gravity form on my WordPress site. I have selected dropdown for state and postcode. I have also checked the **Enhanced user interface** checkbox but, It was not enabling chosen on my dropdown field for a mobile device.

[screensoot of drop-down field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z652R.png)

Is there any options on chosen or gravity form to enable chosen on a mobile device.

Your response really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One year later, there is a possible solution for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741782/390946

I faced today this problem. I used the solution provided above and added an extra action hook for `init` in the theme's `functions.php`, to deregister gravity forms chosen and add the custom script instead.

Example:

```
/**
 * Fix for chose not working on mobile devices.
 */
function [theme alias]_fix_gform_chosen_mobile() {
    wp_deregister_script('gform_chosen');
    wp_register_script('gform_chosen', path_join(get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), 'js/chosen.jquery.fix.min.js'), ['jquery'], '1.10.0-fix');
}
add_action('init', '[theme alias]_fix_gform_chosen_mobile', 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same solution, but updated to fix the syntax issues.

```
/* Fix for chosen not working on mobile devices. */
function theme_alias_fix_gform_chosen_mobile() {
    wp_deregister_script('gform_chosen');
    wp_register_script('gform_chosen', path_join(get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), 'js/chosen.jquery.fix.min.js'), ['jquery'], '1.10.0-fix');
}
add_action('init', 'theme_alias_fix_gform_chosen_mobile', 11);
```

Comment: If you have a small change to add to an answer, you can use the 'Edit' button under that answer instead to improve it.